# Php: Load xml only once in a session

Tags: php, html, ajax, xml, simplexml

I'm using Simplexml in a class to load the appropriate nodes of my xml into html.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
 <item>
  <title>Reminder</title>
 </item>
 <item>
  <title>Work</title>
 </item>
 <item>
  <title>Play</title>
 </item>
 <item>
  <title>Cycling</title>
 </item>
</note>

<?php
    class myxmlclass {      
      private $nodeno;
      private $currenttitle;
      private $myno;
    
      //Load xml
      function loadxm() {
        $filename = 'xmlfile.xml';
        if(file_exists($filename)){
            $selxml=simplexml_load_file("xmlfile.xml", 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA ) or die("Error: Cannot load xml");
            htmlspecialchars($selxml);
            return $selxml;
        }
      }
  }
```

When the page is loaded, the item is selected based on a dynamic number set to a variable $myno:

```
  $currentnode = $selxml->item[(int) $myno];
  $currenttitle = $currentnode->title;
```

This works well when the session starts, but when I access the next and previous item  through ajax call, the xml loads all over again. How can I prevent this from happening? How can I make the xml load only once in a session?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question…but what about store $selxml in the session and check that var during ajax. If present use that otherwise run loadxml ()

Answer (score 1):

The session is basically state. One that is serialized and unserialized between requests.

A SimpleXMLElement can not be serialized, or to be more precise, not on the PHP level as in a session.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed

But you don't need to. Either the XML does not change, then you don't need to put it into the session but only the pointer to the element you're interested in.

Likely this part:

```
$currentnode = $selxml->item[(int) $myno];
                             ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

The session only needs to know the integer `$myno`,

Or the XML does change, then store is as XML - strings can be serialized perfectly in session.

```
$string = $selxml->asXML();
```

and when restoring:

```
$selxml = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

There you have your roundtrip.

The smaller the overall session data is, the better. Start with the pointer to the current element.